# Migrating from Winforms to WPF: OnLoad event

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

In Winforms, we normally use the `OnLoad` event handler (or better, the `OnLoad()` method override) to start working with UI, because we know that at that point everything is ready.

Shall we use the same approach with WPF? When can we consider the UI ready to use in a WPF application?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “working with the UI”?

Comment: When UI controls have a Window handle...

Comment: are you using MVVM or any other MVC pattern, if not then the simple answer is 'yes' to your question

Comment: It is a wide-spread myth that OnLoad is required in a Winforms app to alter properties of controls.  It is only ever needed if you need to know the Size and Location property values.  Everything else belongs in the constructor.  Like it does in WPF.

Comment: In WPF, there is no such thing as "start working with the UI". There is XAML and [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) as opposed to the horrible procedural code hacks you find in archaic technologies. I can't post an answer right now because I need to leave, read the linked MSDN article and forget dinosaur winforms and all it's horrible practices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but we should register for "Loaded" event in XAML side

```
      Loaded="Window_Loaded"
```

and as a result of registering, we use following method on .cs side.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I hope that was you are asking